# Plotly dot plot - how to group multiple columns

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I feel like I'm going crazy trying to figure this out. Supposedly I have this data frame, how can I create a dot plot similar to the graph below? (just the dots and not the bars)

| ProbesetID | bone marrow | bone marrow | kidney | kidney | heart | heart | heart | lungs | spleen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AFFX-r2-Bs-dap-3_at | 120 | 250 | 221 | 150 | 332 | 242 | 400 | 130 | 432 |

Notice how the dots are in the same x-axis if the columns have the same name

[Ideal graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8OK7.jpg)

I tried plotly dot plot but haven't been able to somehow group the columns together.

This is my code

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
  
# initialize list of lists 
data = [['ajfhf',120 , 250, 221 , 150 , 332, 242, 400, 130, 432]] 
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ProbeID', 'bone marrow' , 'bone marrow' ,'kidney' , 'kidney' ,'heart', 'heart' ,' heart' , 'lungs' ,'spleen']) 
cols = df.columns[1:]
print(cols)
fig = go.Figure()  
for col in cols:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        y=df[col],
        name=col
    ))


fig.update_traces(marker_size=10)
fig.show()
```

Here is what it looked like. Notice how they're all stacked on 1 column and some dots are missing. In the go.Scatter part, I had to leave out x axis because I wasn't sure what to use there.

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72tjM.png)